# Programmatically trigger a swipe motion event in Android view

Tags: java, android, android-view

I'm trying to programmatically trigger a swipe in a view. There are other questions with answers but they haven't worked for me. I also saw some [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33698527/trying-to-simulate-swipe-programmatically-in-android) that said programmatic dragging/scrolling was disabled for security reasons, is that true? I'd love to find a definitive answer on this.

I've tried the following method that the [poster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43985415/7613702) showed working via a video, so it *should* work! Is there something I need in my `AndroidManifest`? I've also tried the `scrollBy()` API but that doesn't scroll my content, and instead moves the content offscreen.

What's more, I've registered a `OnTouchListener` with my view and seen that the below code copies the same format of event firing (`ACTION_DOWN`,`ACTION_MOVE`, `ACTION_UP)`that a click+drag, and mouse wheel do, though the click+drag and a mouse wheel works while the programmatic scroll/swipe does not.

```
        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(System.currentTimeMillis(), System.currentTimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 500, 700, 0);
                dispatchTouchEvent(event);
                event.recycle();
            }
        });

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(System.currentTimeMillis(), System.currentTimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, 500, 700 ,0);
                dispatchTouchEvent(event);
                event.recycle();
            }
        }, 50);

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(System.currentTimeMillis(), System.currentTimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, 500 ,700 + 400, 0);
                dispatchTouchEvent(event);
                event.recycle();
            }
        }, 100);

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(System.currentTimeMillis(), System.currentTimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 500, 700 + 400, 0);
                dispatchTouchEvent(event);
                event.recycle();
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my fling method

```
 /**
 * Simulate touching a specific location and dragging to a new location.
 *
 * @param fromX X coordinate of the initial touch, in screen coordinates
 * @param toX Xcoordinate of the drag destination, in screen coordinates
 * @param fromY X coordinate of the initial touch, in screen coordinates
 * @param toY Y coordinate of the drag destination, in screen coordinates
 * @param stepCount How many move steps to include in the drag
 */
 fun fling(
        fromX: Float, toX: Float, fromY: Float,
        toY: Float, stepCount: Int
    ) {

        val inst = Instrumentation()

        val downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()
        var eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()

        var y = fromY
        var x = fromX

        val yStep = (toY - fromY) / stepCount
        val xStep = (toX - fromX) / stepCount

        var event = MotionEvent.obtain(
            downTime, eventTime,
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, fromX, fromY, 0
        )
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
            event.source = InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN
        }
        inst.sendPointerSync(event)



        for (i in 0 until stepCount) {
            y += yStep
            x += xStep
            eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()
            event = MotionEvent.obtain(
                downTime, eventTime + stepCount,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, x, y, 0
            )
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
                event.source = InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN
            }
            inst.sendPointerSync(event)
        }

        eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + stepCount.toLong() + 2
        event = MotionEvent.obtain(
            downTime, eventTime,
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, toX, toY, 0
        )

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
            event.source = InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN
        }
        inst.sendPointerSync(event)
    }
```

And this is how I use it

```
 fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Thread(Runnable {
                try {

                    fling(500f ,900f ,530f ,20f, 5);
                   // emulateMptionEvent()

                } catch (e: Exception) {
                }
            }).start()
        }
```

This is how it works:

Before

[image]

After clicking on Fab Button, Blue dotted line is emulated fling path.

[image]

Comment: how to swipe up ?

Answer (score 0):

With `androidx.test.uiautomator` this is entirely possible - and this is a real-world scenario. I've wrote this method to test an endless scrolling `RecyclerView` ...just because I'm too lazy to swipe:

```
protected void fling(UiObject2 view, int speed, int pause) {
    Assert.assertThat(view, not(equalTo(null)));
    try {
        view.fling(Direction.DOWN, speed);
    } catch (StaleObjectException e) {
        Assert.fail();
    }
    sleep(pause);
}
```

event automation with `adb shell input swipe` is also possible ...

in both cases, the event does not originate from the app, which is tested.

and in both cases, is relies on `android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS`.

on a rooted device, one does not even need `adb` - see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28339954/549372).

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work for me, although my android app is technically a Unity plugin, I believe I need to be able to trigger the swipe/scroll within the app.